# Javascript not populating input value correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a store for my website, and on the item page there are color options. Click on the color option and it changes the photo so show the user, and there's a hidden input who's value is supposed to update with the chosen color, but I can't get it to work right.

In the `$(document).ready(function()` I have Javascript populating that input's value, but it only works occasionally, less often than not. The code I have seems to me like it should work. I'm not sure what I'm missing or doing wrong at this point.

Here's the code

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function color(option) {
        document.getElementById('photo').src = '../img/tshirts/shirts/' + option + '.jpg';
        document.getElementById('item-color').value = option;
    }

</script>
```

In the body:

```
<div id="photo-wrapper">
    <img id="photo" src="../img/tshirts/shirts/charcoal-black.jpg" />
    <input type="hidden" id="item-color" name="item-color" value="charcoal-black" />
    <div id="colors">
        <a href="javascript:color('aqua');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/aqua.png" title="Aqua"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('athletic-grey');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/athletic-grey.png" title="Athletic Grey"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('berry');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/berry.png" title="Berry"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('blue');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/blue.png" title="Blue"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('brown');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/brown.png" title="Brown"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('charcoal-black');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/charcoal-black.png" title="Charcoal Black"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('clay');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/clay.png" title="Clay"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('emerald');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/emerald.png" title="Emerald"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('green');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/green.png" title="Green"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('grey');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/grey.png" title="Grey"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('maroon');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/maroon.png" title="Maroon"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('navy');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/navy.png" title="Navy"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('orange');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/orange.png" title="Orange"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('purple');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/purple.png" title="Purple"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('red');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/red.png" title="Red"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('solid-black');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/solid-black.png" title="Solid Black"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('teal');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/teal.png" title="Teal"/></a>
        <a href="javascript:color('true-royal');"><img class="swatch" src="../img/tshirts/swatches/true-royal.png" title="True Royal"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementById('color-title').html(option);` supposed to do? There's no such of method (`html()`) in HTML elements.

Comment: jQuery has a .html. Do you mean `$('#color-title').html(option);`

Comment: There are no elements in the html that you provided that have ids `color-choice` or `color-title`.

Comment: it's not actually doing anything. That's just the remnants of something I started but decided not to do. I'll take it out so it isn't confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hopefully going to save you a lot of time, don't set the option via JavaScript, set the DEFAULT option via actually putting the value in the hidden input element.

You can change it later with JS.

Comment: I set the value to the default color, but I'm still not able to change it when the user chooses a different color

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your color function. Make sure "option" is correctly set to the color you're passing through. Make sure there is actually an image with the path that is set up (perhaps you're missing some?).

Comment: That's the thing - the image changes perfectly when the user chooses a color. The only thing not happening is populating the value of the hidden input with the correct color

Comment: Are there any console errors? Does "option" have the correct value?

Comment: Also, it's entirely possible your hidden input field is being updated and you just don't see the value updating depending on what tools you are using to watch it.

Comment: An easy way to double check this is to change it to a text field instead of hidden.

Comment: well that's really weird. I changed it to a text input, and it worked just as you thought it might. So I changed it back to a hidden input and now it's working exactly as it should. Thanks for your help!